# multivariate density calculations in R

Tags: r, probability-density, multivariate-partition

I have a data frame of many numeric variables. Is there a way of calculating (not plotting) areas of the global density which are less dense than others? In other words, is there a way of locating areas of the hyperspace which are very sparsely populated with data points?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your dataframe looks like this

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(rnorm(100,0,3),rnorm(100,12,1),rnorm(100,20,3)), 
                 y = c(rnorm(75,5,2),rnorm(75,-5,3),rnorm(140,10,2),rnorm(10,25,10)))
```

You can store each density in a vector

```
dsx <- density(df$x)
dsy <- density(df$y)
```

Now look at the result of `dsx` for instance. You will see that we get a list which contains:

- `dsx$x` coordinates where density is evaluated
- `dsx$y` the estimated density at those coordinates

If you want to find coordinates of areas sparsely populated, you just need to retrieve the coordinates corresponding to low densities.

```
dsx$x[which(dsx$y) < 0.03] # returns coordinates for which density(x) < 0.03
```

To combine all your coordinates (here `x` and `y`), I would create a dataframe with coordinates and their densities and filter it based on the values of densities.

```
df_ds <- data.frame(dsx$x, dsy$x, dsx$y, dsy$y)
df_ds[which((df_ds$dsx.y < 0.03) & (df_ds$dsy.y < 0.01)), c("dsx.x","dsy.x")]
```

By default, you will get `512` values of `density` per coordinate. You may want to increase this step by setting `n` in `density`. Be sure to set the same value on each of your coordinate.

```
dsx <- density(df$x, n=2048)
```

Comment: this is a good option for 1-2D cases, but I need a multivariate estimation, where the multivariate distribution is unknown